# Get start of a time period from repeated groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

**id** - id of place where action happened
**t** - time of action

```
+----+----------+
| id |    t     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 12:10:00 |
|  1 | 12:10:05 |
|  1 | 12:11:00 |
|  1 | 13:04:03 |
|  2 | 14:18:05 |
|  2 | 15:00:09 |
|  3 | 17:33:50 |
|  1 | 20:03:14 |
|  1 | 20:03:55 |
|  1 | 20:10:23 |
+----+----------+
```

Goal is to get this output

```
+----+----------+
| id |  start   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 12:10:00 |
|  2 | 14:18:05 |
|  3 | 17:33:50 |
|  1 | 20:03:14 |
+----+----------+
```

**start** - time of first action at id

Scripts with rank, min, etc. keep grouping rows with **id=1**
I do not know how to resolve this issue and did not find similar post
Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/daeb9/6) with scripts
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem can be termed as gaps-and-islands problem and can be achieved by the difference of row numbers and aggregation.

```
select id,min(t),min(h)
from
(
select id
      ,t
      ,extract(hour from t) h
      ,row_number() over (order by t) as seq1
      ,row_number() over (partition by id order by t) as seq2
  from records
) t
group by id,(seq1-seq2)
order by min(t);
```

Reference: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7579353cbb95a9853cd7ffe80cb82ec)

Comment: Thanks, but what if we need to find **end time** - time of first action on next id (or time of last action if next does not exist)?
So, the desired column is **14:18:05  
17:33:50  
20:03:14  
20:10:23**

Comment: Must be possible using `lead` and `lag` or `first_value`and `last_value`. I would suggest to create another question with details as per SO standard. However  I will try the same and provide you fiddle link.

Comment: Could you check the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2486cd7c71e48de45c0d4867b0123b8f is this what you want ? I didn't add to the answer as it was not part of original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typical gap and islands problem in which you can use some analytic functions such as `ROW_NUMBER()`, `LAG()`, `LEAD()` etc. mostly we consider applying analytic functions twice through manipulating `PARTITION` option, and substracting one result from the other such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.ID, FIRST_VALUE(t) OVER W AS start
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t) 
             - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY t) AS rn        
          FROM (SELECT ID, t FROM records) t) tt WINDOW W AS
          (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY t ROWS 
             BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
 ORDER BY start;

 +----+----------+
 | id |  start   |
 +----+----------+
 |  1 | 12:10:00 |
 |  2 | 14:18:05 |
 |  3 | 17:33:50 |
 |  1 | 20:03:14 |
 +----+----------+
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=19f7871114b49935bb0e2314b263e598)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to solve this is to use `lag()`:

```
select id, t as start
from (select t.*, lag(id) over (order by t) as prev_id
      from t
     ) t
where prev_id is distinct from id;
```

Basically, you just want the values when the `id` changes.

Note:  I think that looking at this as a "typical" gaps-and-islands problem is overkill and complicates the solution.

Comment: to be honest I got this idea of `gaps-and-islands` from your answers and found it very helpful. In this case you say it is overkill and complicates. Looking at both I understand much better the one with row_number and aggregation. Does both solution differs in terms of performance you mean or what ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 . . . There are many ways to approach gaps-and-islands problems.  The difference of row numbers is one method.  But there are more suitable approaches in other cases.